# API Call in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitch

I'm working on using Twitch's API (from an alternate link because of CORS). The html comes back empty when this is ran. Is it because of the callback and what can I do to get the data? I can confirm that the link works and have tried stepping through it with no luck.

```
let usernames = ['freecodecamp'];
let api = '';
let html = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    api = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + usernames[i] + '?callback=?';
    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
      let online = data.stream == null;
      if(online) {
        html += usernames[i] + '\nStatus: Offline';
      }
      else {
        html += usernames[i] + '\nStatus: Online';
      }
    });
  }
  if(html != '') {
    $('#data_display').html('<h1>' + html + '</h1>');
  }
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of `+ '?callback=?'`. Also, might as well use `glitch.me` instead of `gomix.me`. (The latter redirects to the former.) After that, paste your updated code and let us know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous process. Of course your `html` is empty when you put it in `#data_display`. Then, avoid xhr-ing in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Put your last append html block inside the getJSON :

```
$.getJSON(api, function(data) {
  let online = data.stream == null;
  if(online) {
    html = usernames[i] + '\nStatus: Offline';
  }
  else {
    html = usernames[i] + '\nStatus: Online';
  }
  $('#data_display').append('<h1>' + html + '</h1>');
});
```

And also use `.append` instead of `.html` , otherwise it will replace the html inside of `#data_display`.

There is no need to do `html += ....`

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript promise will help with your situation, take jQuery deferred API as an example:

```
function fetchUserStatus(username) {
  var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
  var api = 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + username + '?callback=?';
  $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
    let online = data.stream == null;
    if (online) {
      defer.resolve('Offline');
    } else {
      defer.resolve('Online');
    }
  });
  return defer.promise();
}

let usernames = ['freecodecamp'];
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
  promises.push(fetchUserStatus(usernames[i]));
}
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
  let html = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    html += usernames[i] + '\nStatus: ' + arguments[i];
  }
  $('#data_display').append('<h1>' + html + '</h1>');
});
```

The jQuery when does not support passing an array of promises, that's why the apply function is used, and at the then callback, you'll need to use the `arguments` to refer to all the resolved value from the promises.

Wish this will help.